# Why Does It Take So Long For Google to Crawl or Re-Crawl My Site

Tags: google, search-engines, crawl-rate

My site hasn't yet been crawled and it has been up for (XX) days or hasn't been re-crawled for (XX) days. Why it is taking so long and how can I speed it up.

(Created for the large number of questions seen floating around here to do with crawl frequency which all seem to vary very minimally on a single theme and yet can't strictly be dup'ed with another question due to one small part of it being different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that what may seem like a slow crawl rate may not necessarily be slow and that when it comes to crawl-rates concepts like slow become meaningless.

### My Site Hasn't Been Crawled Yet

First things first, before Google can crawl a new site they need to know it exists. Google gets this information from a number of sources including...

- Existing sites with links to your new site
- Submissions of the fetch as Google form
- Uploading a sitemap for your new site using [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)

When the new site is identified it is placed into a queue to be crawled by one of Google's Googlebot web crawlers. How long it takes from this point can vary from a few hours to a few days or more depending on a number of proprietary factors that Google doesn't publish.

Once the site has had its existing crawl it is now in the Google index and can be searched, it will also be regularly re-crawled.

### My Site Hasn't Been Re-Crawled For (XX) Number of Days

This statement is often made when a site hasn't been re-crawled for anywhere from a few days to a few weeks. Your site not being re-crawled yet doesn't mean that Google has forgotten about you. For newer sites, sites that don't change a huge amount, and sites that have not been deemed by Google to be of high authority the crawl rate is often up to every 2+ weeks. The purpose of this is to not waste resources on re-crawling a site that may or may not have had new content added in the mean time, as well as to not cause an undue load on a website where that load may not be required. The frequency of re-crawls ramps up and ramps down based on the results of previous crawls. If Google does a re-crawl after two weeks and finds a large number of new content and the new content is assessed as being of a high quality then it is more likely that the next crawl interval will be sooner. This is not a hard and fast rule however and as with most things to do with Google and other search engines quality is everything, as such a site that may have been getting crawled every week at one point may find the crawl frequency reduced if the quality of the content on the site is assessed as not being reasonably high or the change frequency of the site is relatively low.

### What Can I Do To Speed This Up?

The first thing I will say it to **not** try to do anything with the intention of speeding up the crawl process for your site. Realistically focusing your energy on improving your site from the point of view of the end user and continuing to increase the valuable content on your site will do more to increase the crawl rate than any tricks or black-hat techniques.

### How Do I Know Something Hasn't Gone Wrong?

The first step is to sign up for Google Webmaster Tools. Using GWT if Google attempts to crawl your site and can't for some reason, or there is an issue with your site that needs to be addressed this is the first place that a notice will be issued. Using this tool you will also be able to see when your site was last indexed, how many pages from your site have been indexed, and other metrics such as those that can be useful in performing your duties as a webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit a page with Google Search Console (with its direct links), the Googlebot is usually very efficient.
Have you received any message from Google in the GSC console?
The only cases I met in several years was due to a penalty because of spam, cloaking, a "heavy" history of the domain name... or a canonical towards the same (and white) page within the whole pages. There are also cases with a "noindex" on each page or the robots.txt with disallow, but I presume this is not the case here.